# understanding module.exports in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

looking at code from https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee/blob/master/src/config/index.coffee#L13 has the following:

```
#### Config file
# Sets application config parameters depending on `env` name
exports.setEnvironment = (env) ->
  console.log "set app environment: #{env}"
  switch(env)
    when "development"
      exports.DEBUG_LOG = true
      exports.DEBUG_WARN = true
      exports.DEBUG_ERROR = true
      exports.DEBUG_CLIENT = true
      exports.DB_HOST = 'localhost'
      exports.DB_PORT = "3306"
      exports.DB_NAME = 'mvc_example'
      exports.DB_USER = 'root'
      exports.DB_PASS = 'root'

    when "testing"
      exports.DEBUG_LOG = true
      exports.DEBUG_WARN = true
      exports.DEBUG_ERROR = true
      exports.DEBUG_CLIENT = true

    when "production"
      exports.DEBUG_LOG = false
      exports.DEBUG_WARN = false
      exports.DEBUG_ERROR = true
      exports.DEBUG_CLIENT = false
    else
      console.log "environment #{env} not found"
```

when i try to output the `modules.export` i get an empty array from the console!

how does one correctly make use of `exports.DB_NAME` if for example i have a module that needs this info?

`console.log config.DB_NAME` returns an `undefined` if called from another module.

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any property set on `exports` is available as a property of the object that is returned when you require the particular module. However, in this case, only one property is set at first: the `setEnvironment` function. The rest is simply undefined at first.

Use it like this:

```
  config = require "./config" # the right path depends on where you're requiring from
  config.setEnvironment "development" # or "testing", "production"
  console.log config.DEBUG_LOG
  console.log config.DB_Name
```